# Youtube API Search & Get list of videos

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using Youtube API to search and get information for videos based on a search word. However, this following code does not return any ID for a video and only gives one thing in return:

```
{"B":{"method":"youtube.search.list","rpcParams":{"type":"video","part":"snippt","q":"party"},"transport":{"name":"googleapis"}}}
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
var search = "party";
var category = "music";

function searchVideos() {

gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
    console.log('youtube API loaded...');

    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        type: 'video',
        part: 'snippt',
        q: search
    });

    var str = JSON.stringify(request);
    alert(str);
  });
}
```

In addition, I want to limit my search to the category that I specified in the javascript code.
Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in:

```
part: 'snippt',
```

it should be

```
part: 'id, snippet',
```

if you want video id's and snippets for the given search query.